# sudo npm install -g ionic not working

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, permissions, npm

I have been trying to install Cordova and ionic on ubuntu 18.04. Cordova installed fine, but ionic generated this error:

```
   WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic
npm ERR! code ELOOP
npm ERR! errno -40
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, access '/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic'
```

I tried upgrading npm to version 6.10.1. Still, it did not work! Also, when I used `ls -la /usr/lib/node_modules`
I got the following:

```
 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root marwa    5 Jul 18 22:32 ionic -> ionic
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not likely a permission issue but instead a file recursion issue.

This happens sometimes when you have a recursive dependency in your `package.json` that asks the system to install a copy of itself.  For instance if you might have a dependency in the file that says

```
"iconic": "file:node_modules/iconic"
```

(or similar) that could cause the kind of symbolic file loop that would generate that kind of error.

You might be able to fix by removing that line in `package.json` and then retrying your install. You might find you don't need to use `sudo`. Here is a help reference for someone else who had a similar issue [error and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45106627/npm-checkpermissions-missing-write-access-to-node-modules-is).

Comment: I have fixed the issue by removing the symbolic link using `sudo rm ionic` and reinstalled ionic. It worked!